# Access local MySQL database via LAN through Visual C++ DLL

Tags: mysql, database, visual-c++, dll, lan

I'm writing a wrapper for a local MySQL database.  So far, I've made a Visual C++ DLL that opens a connection to the database from the local computer using MySQL's C connector.  How can I extend the DLL to access the database remotely through a LAN connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the same concept, but you need to enable remote access on your remote database. This is not really safe if you are doing it over public connection.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html